# sphinx search error on amazon linux

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, amazon-ec2, sphinx

1. I have installed sphinx 2.0.6 version on Amazon Linux.
2. I have run /usr/local/bin/searchd by root user.
3. I have set 777 permission to all (all indexfiles ,searchd.log, query.log, searchd.pid ) to avoid permission issue.
4. I have setup main-delta index.
5. I want that after insert a new record in database, delta index should be updated from  php code. and This new record I want to show to user immediately after insert.
   For this purpose I have used
6. exec(/usr/local/bin/indexer --rotate delta_index) in my php code. and write code to return this new record using sphinxapi.(using codeignitor framework)

   $result = $this->sphinxclient->query($term,'main delta');

   But everytime I do it, it throws an error:

   index 'delta': search error
7. Index files are created on there place. But Search is not working.
8. I have test search from command line also.But following error occurred

   /usr/local/bin/search --index delta test
   Sphinx 2.0.6-release (r3473)

   using config file '/usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf'...
   index 'delta': search error:
9. Please Have anyone any idea where the things go wrong ???
10. Please help me in how to update index after insert on db via php. & how to sphinx search get in working.  Please give me any link, article, guide anything!!!
11. Thanks In Advance....

Yogi

Comment: Avoid 777 in all possible cases, specially if you deal with system package config files. Find alternative way like change ownership to required user. Or gave minimum feasible permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 'php' - ie the webuser - to be able to rebuild the indexer. Best to run searchd as that user. So the same user runs indexer and searchd. often 'www-data' or something like 'apache' - depends on distribution.

Set all sphinx files to be owned by that user, do not set 'execute' bit on the files.

If you get "index 'delta': search error" when trying to run a query, suggests, that the query function is using "search" command under the hood - bad! Use the proper sphinxapi (ie sphinxapi.php) - and if it doesnt work check getLastError/getLastWarning.

Comment: Thanks Barry ...Tips are very useful. My problem is resolved... by doing 1. starting searchd service by apache user.... "sudo -u apache /usr/local/bin/searchd "  2. setting appropriate permission to all indexfiles, searchd.pid,bin folder etc.... 3. using sphinxapi.api